# how to slice background color with before/after element

Tags: html, css, background-color

[please have a look at my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfPdk.png)I have added background color, and now i want to slice some point and must be with background transparent like i added

```
.single_cat_list_in .meta:before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ffffff !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: -35px;
    bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

https://prnt.sc/pi94k5

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple linear and radial gradients to create the rounded corners (taken from this [article](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/)):

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
 background:
  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, gold 0) top left,
  linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, gold 0) top right,
  linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, white 0) bottom right,
  linear-gradient(135deg,  transparent 10px, white 0) bottom left;

 background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, transparent 14px, gold 15px),
  radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 14px, gold 15px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 14px, white 15px),
  radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 14px, white 15px);

 background-size: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for it, but how can i do that for both color, like top and bottom background color?

Comment: Maybe adding it as a PNG Image is better option here. as you need transparent circles here